# Guice, binding to enum

Tags: java, enums, guice

I am having hard time figuring out how to bind interface to enum using Guice.

```
public interface Snack {
    public int caloriesCount();
}

public enum Chocolate implements Snack {
    MILK(20),
    DARK(5),
    WHITE(10);

    private int calCount;

    private Chocolate(int calCount) {
        this.calCount = calCount;
    }

    @Override
    public int caloriesCount() {
        return calCount;
    }   
}
```

If I try:
`bind(Snack.class).to(Chocolate.class);`

I get `No implementation for Chocolate was bound`

I understand that instead of trying to bind to the enum I should bind to the set of that enum's values, but it defies me how that can be accomplished.
Appreciate any hints.
Thanks,
Maciek

Comment: can someone please help me understand `why the question upvotes are far less than the accepted answer`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Binding to an enum class like that is impossible, because Guice cannot create its own instance. Here, the default behavior would be to create a new instance of `Chocolate`, which doesn't make a lot of sense—[every possible instance of an enum must be declared at compile time within the enum itself](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), and Guice won't pick an arbitrary existing one for you.

You might want to do one of these three things instead:

1. Bind `Snack` to a particular type of `Chocolate`.

   ```
   bind(Snack.class).toInstance(Chocolate.DARK);
   ```
2. Bind `Snack` to `Chocolate`, and `Chocolate` to a particular type of `Chocolate`. This is like the above, but now you can ask for `Chocolate` directly and get an instance, instead of only being able to ask for a `Snack`.

   ```
   bind(Snack.class).to(Chocolate.class);
   bind(Chocolate.class).toInstance(Chocolate.DARK);
   ```
3. Allow developers to inject a `Set<Snack>`, which happens to return all `Chocolate` instances.

   ```
   // manual wildcard required so we don't get an ImmutableSet<Chocolate>
   Set<Snack> setOfSnacks = ImmutableSet.<Snack>copyOf(Chocolate.values());

   // bind a Set<Snack> specifically
   bind(new TypeLiteral<Set<Snack>>() {}).toInstance(setOfSnacks);
   ```

   You can use any Set implementation, but because all `toInstance` bindings are implicitly singletons, you can reduce some risk of modification if you use [Guava's `ImmutableSet`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html) or at least [`Collections.unmodifiableSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet(java.util.Set)). If this is close to what you want, you may be interested in learning about the optional [Multibindings plugin](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Multibindings).

   Of course you could also write your own `Provider<Set<Snack>>` or a method that `@Provides Set<Snack>`, thereby getting a new set instance every time...but if you expect to use this across your app it may make more sense to share one immutable copy.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It works and I am off to study Multibindings now.